# beamer: column background color

Tags: beamer, color, columns

How do I change the background color of a column in Beamer? (the entire column)

(This is a simple question, but for the life of me, I cannot not find an answer.)

Example:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1em, text margin right=1em}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
Some text.
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
Some question.
\[1+1=2\]
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What I would like:

[image: example desired result]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two options.

1. Since `minipage` lets you control its height, instead of `columns` I'd rather use two side-by-side `minipage`s, enclosing one of them in a `\colorbox`:

   [image]

   The code:

   ```
   \documentclass[t]{beamer}
   \setbeamersize{text margin left=1em, text margin right=1em}
   \begin{document}

   \begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Test}

   \colorbox{blue!20}{\begin{minipage}[t][0.8\textheight][t]
   {\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule-5pt\relax}
   Some text.
   \end{minipage}}\hfill
   \begin{minipage}[t][0.8\textheight][t]
   {\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-5pt\relax}
   Some question.
   \[1+1=2\]
   \end{minipage}
   \end{frame}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Using a `tabular` and `\columncolor`; an invidible `\rule` of appropriate depth allows you to vertically extend the colorized colum:

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass[table]{beamer}
   \setbeamersize{text margin left=1em, text margin right=1em}
   \begin{document}

   \begin{frame}[t]
   \frametitle{Test}

   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\columncolor{blue!20}\rule[-.8\textheight]{0pt}{0pt}}p{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}p{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}
   Some text. & 
   Some question.
   \[1+1=2\]
   \end{tabular}
   \end{frame}

   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: I am going to give other ppl a chance at answering this; but yeah, I think I will just go with minipages ...

Comment: @RicardoCruz In the meantime I updated my answer with another (simpler) option using a `tabular`.

Comment: A possible alternative as well... Thank you!