# Can I make a beamer slide with two columns where each column has a different background colour?

Tags: beamer, color, columns, backgrounds

I know how to set a background colour for the whole slide, but can I make one column have a different background (and font) colour? Ideally not just by setting a static two-colour background, as I might want to change the column width and not have to remake the background image.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/255915/117727). Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [beamer: column background color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255915/beamer-column-background-color)

Comment: @Sam yes that's great, I couldn't find it before but maybe I was searching the british spelling?